# Fractional display scaling: get and set in terminal

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-gnome, wayland, scaling, hdpi

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 with Wayland. How do I get current fractional scaling value via terminal?

E.g. with GUI set to 125%:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor
```

returns 0, and

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

returns 1.0.

Can't see anything relevant in the list of other `org.gnome.desktop.interface` variables.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using X or Wayland?

Comment: I have the same question for Ubuntu 23.04 using Wayland.

Comment: @Flimm Ubu 22, whatever is default on it

Comment: There's actually two versions of Ubuntu that could be, either Ubuntu 22.04 or Ubuntu 22.10. You can find out by opening "About" in the "Settings" application. You can also find out if you are using X or Wayland from the same place, listed under "Windowing System"

Comment: @Flimm 22.10 wayland

Comment: AFAIK You won't find it because GTK4 doesn't really fractional scaling [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#Fractional_scaling) [2](https://youtu.be/87W6iIEicoM?t=108). Test any change on dconf with `dconf dump / > before/after`